# Xcode 7.1.1 installation fails

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode7

While trying to install Xcode 7 from dmg file by double clicking the Xcode icon, I got the famous GUI with the Xcode icon on one side the the application icon on the other size.

However, as you can see below, there's "non entry sign" over the Xcode icon,   which prevent me from dragging it to the /Application folder.

[image]

Trying to do it manually, by opening Xcode.app from the mount point, I got the following error :

```
LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10825 for the file /Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app
```

On other computer, I did the same experiment with the exact dmg file, and it worked. Any idea what can lead to this problem ?

Comment: which version of OS do you have?

Comment: @RajendrasinhParmar, it's 10.10.3.

Comment: To install xcode 7 or higher you have to have minimum os  must be equal or higher than yosemite.

Comment: but i have yosemite, maybe i need to upgrade to 10.10.5 ?

Comment: yeah you should try upgrading OS first.
mostly this type of problems are compatibility related.

Comment: minimum OS version for xcode 7.0.1 and 7.0 is 10.10.4 
and for xcode 7.1.1 and 7.2 minimum is 10.10.5

Comment: I just wonder whether this is a real requirement, or just an excuse to make people upgrade their OS ?

Comment: i faced same problem while installing xcode 6.4 in older OS.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Comment: Questions about installing XCode are on topic, as per the faq, as XCode is a specifically programming-related application, so using and install it is on topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [App Store listing](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?ls=1&mt=12) for Xcode 7.1.1, OS X 10.10.5 or later is required.

> **Compatibility:** OS X 10.10.5 or later

You need to update OS X on your development machine, or use an earlier version of Xcode.